# Missing font shapes/series

Tags: fonts

I'm having some problems with missing font shapes. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Lato font}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbackslash{}textsc \textsc{No Small Caps!}

\item \textbackslash{}emph \emph{works as expected}

\item \textbackslash{}itshape\textbackslash{}scshape
  {\itshape\scshape Normal font}

\item \textbackslash{}emph\{\textbackslash{}textsc{}\{\}\}
  \emph{\textsc{Also Generates Normal Font}}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

It's slightly better with the default font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Default font}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbackslash{}textsc \textsc{Produces Small Caps}

\item \textbackslash{}emph \emph{works as expected}

\item \textbackslash{}itshape\textbackslash{}scshape
  {\itshape\scshape Generates Small Caps, No Italics}

\item \textbackslash{}emph\{\textbackslash{}textsc{}\{\}\}
  \emph{\textsc{Also Generates Small Caps, No Italics}}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A document I compiled with the same style files a few weeks ago worked with the Lato font, giving me combined italic/small caps without problem:

[image]

How can get my fonts to work again?

## System info:

- Debian Linux (testing)
- texlive package 2017.20171128-1_all
- texlive-fonts-extra 2017.20171128-1_all.deb
- latex --version

> pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
>   kpathsea version 6.2.3
>   Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
>   Compiled with libpng 1.6.32; using libpng 1.6.34
>   Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
>   Compiled with poppler version 0.57.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lato simply does not provide small caps anymore.  From the manual

> #### 4.1.2 Smallcaps
>
> Since the Lato font family doesn’t provide yet “real” smallcaps, faked ones were supplied by previous versions of the `lato` package (by scaling down uppercase letters), with a very poor result. Furthermore, there’s no convenient way to generate fake smallcaps with XeTeX or LuaTeX engines and native OpenType fonts.
>
> For these reasons, faked small caps are no longer provided, starting with version 3.0 of the `lato` package. Anyway LaTeX should automatically substitute missing smallcap shapes by normal ones.

Comment: oh no! That's really too bad, the fake small caps looked quite acceptable to me. I would rather have fakes than none at all.

Answer (score 4):

It works if you load a font with both small-caps and italic small-caps.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\begin{document}

\section{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbackslash{}textsc \textsc{Produces Small Caps}

\item \textbackslash{}emph \emph{works as expected}

\item \textbackslash{}itshape\textbackslash{}scshape
  {\itshape\scshape Generates Italic Small Caps}

\item \textbackslash{}emph\{\textbackslash{}textsc{}\{\}\}
  \emph{\textsc{Also Generates Italic Small Caps}}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: small-caps, italics & italic small-caps]

At least, it works if the support package 'extends' NFSS appropriately. The above won't work with `lmodern`, for example, even though `cfr-lm` and `lmodern` use the same fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\section{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbackslash{}textsc \textsc{Produces Small Caps}

\item \textbackslash{}emph \emph{works as expected}

\item \textbackslash{}itshape\textbackslash{}scshape
  {\itshape\scshape Generates Small Caps, No Italics}

\item \textbackslash{}emph\{\textbackslash{}textsc{}\{\}\}
  \emph{\textsc{Also Generates Small Caps, No Italics}}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: no italic small-caps]

Italic small-caps are missing because they are not supported by NFSS and `lmodern` limits its support for Latin Modern to font dimensions supported by NFSS. The key problem here is that both small-caps and italic are coded as 'font shape', so they cannot be combined without trickery within the framework NFSS provides.

Comment: is there a way to search for available TeX fonts that provide italic small caps, other than looking through each one?

Comment: @HenriMenke Oops - thanks for changing the picture.

Comment: @Tyler The Latex Font Catalogue has samples, but I doubt they cover this. I don't know of a good way to find them. You can't generate a font sampler to check, because different packages implement different interfaces for their NFSS extensions. So code which gets italic small-caps for one font may not get it for another. Not only this, but the shape codes used in the `.fd` files differ, too. But italic small-caps are not usual, so you are not going to find many of them regardless.

Comment: For some fonts, you can tell by their names. But this only really applies to those which use Karl Berry's naming scheme or the verbose scheme generated by `autoinst` et al. And many fonts are not named according to either schema. (However, such fonts are unlikely to have support for italic small-caps with traditional TeX engines, even if the fonts are there.)

Comment: The LaTeX font catalogue for Lato does show examples of sc it, but as pointed out by @HenriMenke this is now outdated. It would be nice to have a database that enabled searching by feature, for those of us with unusual requirements.